# Highlight cells when a cell changes via formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create a macro on Excel to highlight a range of cells when the date in a particular cell changes. The cell draws the date information from Bloomberg (BDP formula), and the workbook refreshes daily.

I've tried this solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

(https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/trigger-your-vba-macros-to-run-based-on-specific-cell-value-change).

However, it only works when the formula in the cell changes, and not when the cell automatically updates the date information when refreshed.

Is there a simple solution to my problem?

Comment: try conditional formatting: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Answer (score 3):

If what you want to detect is just one cell, the solution is perhaps easy. Put a `Worksheet_Calculate` event in the worksheet that contains this cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
     Static oldVal As Variant
     If Me.Range("A1").Value <> oldVal Then
        Me.Range("A2:C4").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
    oldVal = Me.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

This supposes you want to detect the change in cell `A1` and the range you want to highlight is `A2:C4`. Adjust these ranges to your need.